# Using a for loop in R to assign value labels

Tags: r, loops

**Context:** I have a  large dataset (CoreData) with an accompanying datafile (CoreValues) that contains the code and values for each variable within the dataset.

**Problem:** I want to use a loop to assign each variable within the dataset (CoreData) the correct value labels (from the CoreValues data).

**What I've tried so far:**

- I have created a character vector that identifies which variables within my main data (CoreData) have values that need to be added:

```
    Core_VarwithValueLabels<- unique(CoreValues$Abbreviation)
```

- I have tried a for loop using the vector created , to create vectors for both the label and level arguments that feed into the factor() function.

```
    for (i in Core_VarwithValueLabels){
  
    assign(paste0(i, 'Labels'), 
         CoreValues %>% 
         filter(Abbreviation == i) %>% 
        select(Description) %>% 
        unique() %>% 
        unlist()
    )
  
    assign(paste0(i, 'Levels'),
         CoreValues %>% 
           filter(Abbreviation == i) %>% 
           select(Code) %>% 
           unique() %>% 
           unlist()
    )
  
    CoreData[i] <- factor(CoreData[i], levels=paste0(i, 'Levels'), labels = paste0(i, 'Labels'))
  
  }
```

This creates the correct label and level vectors, however, they are not being picked up properly within the factor function.

**Question:** Can you help me identify how to get my factor function to work within this loop or if there is a more appropriate method?

**Sample data:**

CoreValues:
[example data from CoreValues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw1JT.png)

CoreData:
[example data from CoreData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF3FS.png)

**UPDATE: RESOLVED**
I have now resolved this by using the `get()` function within my `factor()` function as it uses the strings I've created with `paste0()` and find the vector of that name.

```
for (i in Core_VarwithValueLabels){
  
  assign(paste0(i, 'Labels'), 
         CoreValues %>% 
         filter(Abbreviation == i) %>% 
        select(Description) %>% 
        unique() %>% 
        unlist()
  )
  
  assign(paste0(i, 'Levels'),
         CoreValues %>% 
           filter(Abbreviation == i) %>% 
           select(Code) %>% 
           unique() %>% 
           unlist()
  )
  
  CoreData[i] <- factor(CoreData[i], levels=get(paste0(i, 'Levels')), labels = get(paste0(i, 'Labels')))
  
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample code using `dput(CoreData)`?

Comment: I can't share the exact data but have updated the question with example data that captures how both datasets are set up.

Comment: Please share sample data as something we can run your code on, not as pictures.  Valid R syntax that we can copy/paste to create the data is best. `dput()` is very helpful for sharing sample data in copy/pasteable valid syntax including class and structure information.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Julian and @GregorThomas. Please see example data using `dput()`:
> dput(CoreData)
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Mode = c(2, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), Sex = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), Length = c(1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4), CourseID = c("10000AB4", 
"10000AB5", "10000AB6", "10000AB7", "10000AB8", "10000AB9", "1000AC71", 
"1000AB11", "1000BR58", "1000AB13")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

Comment: `dput(CoreValues)`:
structure(list(Number = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Code = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Description = c("Part-time", "Full-time", 
"Male", "Female", "Years", "Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours"
), Name = c("Mode of study", "Mode of study", "Sex of student", 
"Sex of student", "Length of study", "Length of study", "Length of study", 
"Length of study", "Length of study"), Abbreviation = c("Mode", 
"Mode", "Sex", "Sex", "Length", "Length", "Length", "Length", 
"Length")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have now resolved this by using the `get()` function within my `factor()` function as it uses the strings I've created with `paste0()` and finds the vector of that name.